# Nutch fetch failed with http code 417

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

Apache nutch fetch step fetches data from url database but only for one site all the featch requests fail with message

```
fetch of https://www.example.com/ failed with: Http code=417,
```

I tried to look on net for possible reason or to config settting but I did not find anything helpful.

Thanks in advance.